# How to make another tag behave exactly like the pre tag using CSS?

Tags: html, css, pre

I want `<code>` tags to behave like `<pre>` tags. But the problem is that I get a line break at the beginning of the block. How do I get rid of that line break?

This shows what I mean ...

http://jsfiddle.net/6NmPN/

Comment: what's wrong with `<pre>`? I like `<pre>`

Comment: I think it's impossible and pre is just fine ;-)

Comment: I don't see anythign wrong in IE. What browser are you targeting?

Comment: @Thomas - firefox, chrome, opera, ie9

Comment: So what's wrong? I see no break except between `pre` and `code` as oblig poitns out.

Comment: @Stefan and @hunter: Technically there is nothing wrong with pre. The philosophies of it is a separate discussion.

Comment: So, don't put a newline after the opening <code> tag!  If this offends you, look for a different line of work, as HTML and programming are rife with annoyances like this.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a browser bug. See e.g. [this page](http://xahlee.info/js/linebreak_after_tag.html). SGML (and thus HTML) says that the browser needs to remove a newline immediately following an opening tag, or immediately preceding a closing tag. But it appears that most browsers (note: not all) only adhere to this requirement on the `<pre>` tag and not on other tags such as the `<code>` tag.

So, it appears there's not much you can do about it. The only possible fix I can think of is using XHTML strict. That's XML, not SGML. Perhaps browsers will treat all elements equally then. I'm not sure, it's just an idea.

Comment: I checked this with XHTML1 Strict: No go. +1 For the explanation.

Comment: This ***almost*** works: `pre:before{content:"\00000a";}` BUT, it doesn't work when there is not a newline after the opening tag(s). Unsolvable?

Comment: penny for your thoughts, but unfortunately didn't work even with xhtml.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, this is not a browser bug. The HTML5 specification says this for [the pre element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/grouping-content.html#the-pre-element)

> In the HTML syntax, a leading newline
>   character immediately following the
>   pre element start tag is stripped.

and in the tree construction stage of the parser, for the [in body](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/tree-construction.html#parsing-main-inbody) mode:

> A start tag whose tag name is one of:
>   "pre", "listing"
>
> ...
>
> Insert an HTML element for the token.
>
> If the next token is a U+000A LINE FEED (LF) character token, then ignore
>   that token and move on to the next
>   one. (Newlines at the start of pre
>   blocks are ignored as an authoring
>   convenience.)
>
> ...

As others have said, there's no way of emulating this behaviour with CSS. You could, of course, remove any initial line feeds of `<code>` elements with JavaScript.

Note that this says, `"In the HTML syntax ..."`. This would not happen if the page was XHTML-conformant *and* it was served with an XML content type. e.g. application/xhtml+xml. In that mode, both `pre` and `code` would have the extra line at the start. However, this is not supported in IE versions prior to IE9.

Comment: I [uploaded a test](http://wesleymurch.com/test/code_pre_newline_test.html) with the specs you mentioned and it still seems to do the same thing, at least in FF4 and Chrome 10. IE seems to be the only one that does not add the newline, but I am unable to test IE9. This is interesting stuff (yes I am boring), so thanks for sharing this Alochi.

Comment: @Madmartigan - That test isn't being served as application/xhtml+xml, it's being served as text/html. The content type has to given in the real HTTP header, not in an http-equiv meta tag. (Unless the **web server** converts the http-equiv setting to a real HTTP header, which is allowed but in practice is extremely rare)

Comment: @Madmartigan - To demonstrate, here's your test case served as text/html: http://www.alohci.net/text/html/code_pre_newline_test.html.ashx and here's the exact same file served as application/xhtml+xml: http://www.alohci.net/application/xhtml+xml/code_pre_newline_test.html.ashx

Comment: Hmm, I moved it to a php file and tried again, with both  application/xml and application/xhtml+xml set with php header(). I'm seeing it in the header in Firebug but no difference in display. EDIT: Aha! OK, I'm seeing it now both on my test and yours. That's great, thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score -3):

If you look at inspect element in chrome of your code:

```
<body>
  <pre>foo 1
foo  2
foo 3
</pre>
<br>
<code>
bar 1
bar  2
bar 3
</code>
</body>
```

it removes all whitespce before the 1st character in the pre but not in the code tag.

try doing this in the code tag:

```
<code>bar 1
bar  2
bar 3
</code>
```

Comment: This does not make the two tags **behave** the same way.

Comment: @Madmartigan, yes it does. for some reason there is glitch in those browsers that **removes** the whitespace, there is nothing you can really do to emulate that

Comment: I doubt its a glitch as it happens in every browser, except old versions of Internet explorer.

Comment: @Neal: It doesn't quite do the same thing, because you have different formatting in each tag. OP is not looking for a specific fix for this exact code, he's looking for either a CSS solution or an explanation. (I believe, could be wrong). I think this is a good question so I would like to see good knowledgeable answers.

Comment: @Madmartigan, i gave an explanation of why its happening and how he can resolve it.

Comment: @Madmartigan, That's exactly what I mean.