# How to 'hide' :first-line for white-space:pre-line in FIREFOX browser

Tags: html, css, firefox

When I use

```
white-space: pre-line;
word-break: break-word;
```

...there is one additionl line before text. To hide it, I used:

```
.class:first-line { line-height: 0; }
```

...and it is working in Chrome browser, but not in the Firefox.

Here is a working fiddle and please **open it in Firefox** : https://jsfiddle.net/t3qj51co/2/

[image]

Comment: Removed Javascript tag as it's not a part of the problem.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes k :) I see that you removed p.s part also.. thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Why not just fix your HTML ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/t3qj51co/3/))

The problem is that  in your html you have an empty line. Since you use `pre-line` it takes that into account as well.

Just removing the empty line fixes it.

---

The issue is that firefox does not allow to decrease the `line-height` more than the currently active one.

At first this looks like a Firefox bug (*it works as described in the OP in Chrome, IE, Safari*).
But reading the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-line) i see that it is open to interpretation as it says that

> This paragraph might be "*rewritten*" by user agents to include the fictional tag sequence for ***::first-line***. This fictional tag sequence helps to show how properties are inherited.

If a UA follows this approach then it is valid to not decrease the visual height of the line, as it only applies to the "fictional tag". (*a nested tag cannot influence the `line-height` of its container downwards*)

So not sure if it is an actual bug (*on either spectrum of browsers*) or a valid difference in implementations.

Comment: Hehe I like this one :)

Comment: @DejanMunjiza Besides that, it looks like a bug on firefox that does not allow a `line-height` of less than the inherited one (*which applies to the rest of the element*)

Comment: Yes, I decided to leave question for some time and see if someone maybe have some 'workaround' for this Firefox issue. You will definitely get credit since this helped me.

Comment: If you have to allow free text that might have new lines at the top, then i would use some JS to trim empty lines from the beginning of element.

Comment: If you have a moment, please provide a quick example link with js solution.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/t3qj51co/4/ (*it removes all leading whitespace. It will remove more than one empty lines if they exist at the start*)

Comment: Thank you Gaby. This will help me in future I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Just write your HTML like this:

```
<div class="test">Don't press a carriage return after an opening div and continue typing....

This is the next paragraph and at the end, just close the div like this.</div>
```

If you use template code, just do like this:

```
<div class="test">{{{MustacheDataHere}}}</div>
```

No need to put this `.test:first-line { line-height: 0; }` in your `.test` class. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48183749/2200913) for more info.

Comment: I encountered a similar issue. My problem was, that my "prettier" reformatted the code on save and added a new line to the HTML for readability reasons. "white-space: pre-line" keeps this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to botch my way to obtain the same results in FF and Chrome by adding a negative margin; see the content in `.new`:

```css
.class {
  white-space: pre-line;
}

.class::first-line {
  line-height: 0;
}

.new:before {
  content: '';
  margin: -1.5em 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<hr>
<div class='class'>
    line #1
    line #2
    line #3
</div>
<hr>
<div class='class new'>
    line #1
    line #2
    line #3
</div>
```

| Chrome | Firefox |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Chrome] | [image: FireFox] |