# What is and how can I remove/reduce the whitespace before and after preformatted code?

Tags: html, css, code-formatting, pre

Here's an HTML showing some code in between two short lines of text

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Uffa</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
pre {
  margin: 0;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    line before
    <pre><code>
some
  code
    here
    </code></pre>
    line after
  </body>
</html>
```

When I hover with the mouse via devtools, I see this:

[image]

and I don't understand where the vertical spacing before and after the code chunk comes from.

Below is the live snippet, in which, however, only the top space of my example is reproduced.

```css
pre {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
line before
<pre><code>
some
  code
    here
</code></pre>
line after
```

---

I have simplified my use case a lot to ask this question. And after the the simplification, I still see the same issue I was concerned about.

However, as somebody suggested to use `<pre>` without nesting `<code>` into it, I should probably clarify that in the original use case, I'm making use of [`highlight.js`](https://highlightjs.org/usage/), which prescribes to write code in between `<pre><code class="language-whatever">` and `</code></pre>`.

Comment: it's the line return, everything inside pre show as it is

Comment: Try writing content (some...) on the same line as <pre> tag. Content inside <pre> is shown as it was written.

Comment: Technically I knew what `<pre>` was for... I just didn't think of the first and last character. Thanks. I guess anybody can post that as an answer. By the way, is there an "option" or something to tell `<pre>` to ignore leading and trailing `\n`s? This way, I could keep the code on its own lines

Comment: @TemaniAfif, why doens't the live snippet show the space between `here` and _line after_, considering that there is a `\n` between `here` and `</code></pre>`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove leading whitespace from whitespace: pre element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17365838/remove-leading-whitespace-from-whitespace-pre-element)

Comment: For the first-line whitespace you can use `pre:first-line {
    line-height: 0px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```css
code {
  white-space: break-spaces;
}
```

```html
line before
<code>
some
  code
    here
</code> line after
```

Comment: Would be nice to have a reference. [_CSS `white-space` Property_](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) doesn't seem to refer to `break-spaces`.

Comment: Oh, well, [MDN Wed Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) gives a better view on that.

Comment: @Enlico the pre was removed here so this is a complete different code giving another different result

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I hadn't noticed `<pre>` was removed. Which kind of makes this a non-answer. Thanks for pointing that out.